# Unable to edit text in HTML without changing CSS/styling

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm unable to edit a h1 tag without changing the css. Here is the string without the javascript:
[image: without JS]

Here is the string with the javascript:
[image: with js]

I'm not having this problem elsewhere. THe rest of the code snippets were properly manipulated by the JS code.
Here is the HTML and JS snippets:

```
document.getElementById('currentContact').innerText = state.translate('test');
```

```
  <div class="class_Name" id="currentContact">
                    <h1>test</h1>
                </div>
```

Troubleshooting:

- Tried moving the div to between the  tags
- Tried innerHTML, textContents, innerText.

I expect the manipulated string to keep the same styling.

Comment: Your `currentContact` is the `<div>` that contains the `<h1>`. If you change the `innerText ` of `currentContact`, it will completely override the `<h1>`.

Comment: You are changing the contents of the `<div>` around the `<h1>`, rather than the contents of the `<h1>` itself. Perhaps consider `document.querySelector("#currentContact > h1").innerText = ...` instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `currentContact` is the `<div>` that contains the `<h1>`. If you change the `innerText`  of `currentContact`, it will completely override the `<h1>`.

As a solution, you could give your `<h1>` element the id `currentContact`. or insert a new `<h1>` when you assign a new value to `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

```js
document.getElementById('currentContact').innerText = "el testo";
```

```html
<div class="class_Name" >
    <h1 id="currentContact">test</h1>
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('currentContact').innerHTML = "<h1>el testo</h1>";
```

```html
<div class="class_Name" id="currentContact">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a working code snippet AND explaining what I did incorrect. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are replacing the `<h1>` element when you set the `innerText` property. Target and manipulate the `<h1>` element inside the `<div>` instead, like:

```js
const state = { translate: () => 'foo' };

document.querySelector('#currentContact h1').innerText = state.translate('test');
```

```html
<div class="class_Name" id="currentContact">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That explained the issue

Answer (score -1):

try stuffing
document.getElementById('currentContact').innerText = state.translate('test');
to a variable, like let text, then call text.style.color = 'red';
maybe I misunderstood your question